# Magento2: Override ViewModel

Tags: magento2, viewmodel

Is there a way to override ViewModel Function

I Have a installed a Module in vendor but I  want to override Function of ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

You still be able to using preference or plugin for the ViewModel Class.

For example `Magento\Customer\ViewModel\Address`

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\ViewModel\Address" type="Foo\Bar\ViewModel\Address"/>

<type name="Magento\Customer\ViewModel\Address">
        <plugin sortOrder="10" name="Foo_Bar::do_stuff" type="Foo\Bar\Plugin\ViewModel\AddressPlugin"/>
</type>
```